# Copy range from closed workbook - Error 1004 FormulaArray

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a range value from a specific sheet in a closed workbook.
The code I am using is as follow:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range(cellrange)
 'Assigning the array formula to the specified range
     .FormulaArray = "='" & fPath & "\[" & fName & "]" & sName & "'!" & cellrange
 'Removing formula from the cell and pasting the values in the cell
     .Value = .Value
End With
```

however when I run it, it gives

> Error 1004: Unable to set the Formula Array property of the Range
>   class.

The (file path + file name + sheet name + range) length is less than 255 characters, anyone can help?
The funny part is that yesterday i run the same code and it was working!!

Comment: Can you show the code that declares the variables

Comment: `The (file path + file name + sheet name + range) length is less than 255 characters` Can you confirm it for me? Try this `Dim sFormula As String : sFormula = "='" & fPath & "\[" & fName & "]" & sName & "'!" & cellrange` and then in the next line `Msgbox sFormula`. What do you get?

Comment: I got an empty msgbox which means sFromula  is empty

Comment: `I got an empty msgbox which means sFromula is empty – Dona Chlela 1 min ago` There you go :)

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` on top of your code. That will help

Comment: Option explicit didn't fix it

Comment: Can you post your complete code (including my suggestion in the first comment)?

Comment: I got the following msgbox: ='Z:\3. Internal Commercial Reporting\Commercial Overview\1. Project Commercial Registers\19.12\[SC-114-Commercial Register_19.12_00.xlsx]PPC & Invoice Log'!A1:AA100

Comment: too long i can't post it in a comment

Comment: No worries. At least you are now getting some value in the msgbox. Earlier you mentioned you were getting nothing. Now replace `Msgbox sFormula` with `Msgbox Len(sFormula)`. What do you get?

Comment: the length I got in the msgbox is 165

Comment: Then it should work. Hmm this is strange

Comment: I solved it, I should have used .Formula instead of .FormulaArray